# Processing Unicode strings in returned JSON data

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am trying to print data from fetched JSON, however the data has unicode-decoded data. How can I encode (see example) it to display correctly. I am very new to python and was not able to get it working, I am using Windows 7, python 2.7 on a command line terminal. Thanks!

Example: results>>title:

'R\u00f6yksopp - 49 Percent' has to print it as 'Röyksopp - 49 Percent'

```
"title": "R\u00f6yksopp - 49 Percent",
```

JSON:

```
"results": [{
        "style": ["House", "Electro", "Synth-pop"],
        "thumb": "http://api.discogs.com/image/R-90-530519-1236701656.jpeg",
        "format": ["CD", "Maxi-Single"],
        "country": "Europe",
        "barcode": ["5 028589 023420", "BEL/BIEM", "LC 3098"],
        "uri": "/R%C3%B6yksopp-49-Percent/master/30161",
        "label": ["Virgin", "Labels", "Wall Of Sound"],
        "catno": "0946 3378752 0",
        "year": "2005",
        "genre": ["Electronic"],
        "title": "R\u00f6yksopp - 49 Percent",
        "resource_url": "http://api.discogs.com/masters/30161",
        "type": "master",
        "id": 30161
    }
```

Comment: `\u00f6` is `ö`. Does Command Prompt support those characters?

Comment: Do you use a lib to parse json ? (do you "import json" or "import cjson" ?)

Comment: Show the actual Python code that you used, and what output you got.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json


d = json.loads(u'''{"title": "R\u00f6yksopp - 49 Percent"}''')
print d['title'].encode('utf-8')`

Comment: The above code doest not print correctly..

Comment: Output: `R├╢yksopp - 49 Percent`

Answer (score 1):

Environment: Windows 7, default codepage = 850, Python 2.7.3

Using a cut-down version of your input:

```
>>> import json
>>> js = """{
...         "style": ["House", "Electro", "Synth-pop"],
...         "title": "R\u00f6yksopp - 49 Percent",
...         "id": 30161
...     }"""
>>>
>>> j = json.loads(js)
>>> j
{u'style': [u'House', u'Electro', u'Synth-pop'], u'id': 30161, u'title': u'R\xf6yksopp - 49 Percent'}
>>> j['title']
u'R\xf6yksopp - 49 Percent'
>>> print j['title']
Röyksopp - 49 Percent
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately my unicode string varies from request to request, for example, the code mentioned below wont output on my terminal, but the above code you posted works only for that symbol listed..I was looking at a generic solution to any unicode characters...<br><br>

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
js = """{"style": ["House", "Electro", "Synth-pop"],"title": "Gigi D\u2010Agostino - The Riddle","id": 30161}"""
j = json.loads(js)
print j['title']` - Here u\2010 is a hyphen ( I think) that wont display...I shall paste the terminal error I get below..

Comment: `print j['title']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2010' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: There is no good generic solution for the Windows commandline. Try IDLE.